# Запятая или всё-с тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильны ли оба варианта? Мне кажется, что тут – в 4-м пункте 65-го пар. – говориться, что да: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

`Эти экзаменаторы – злыдни, как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся.`

`Эти экзаменаторы, злыдни, как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся.`

Или надо так?

`Эти экзаменаторы-злыдни, как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз предирутся.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корректное оформление:

(1) *Эти экзаменаторы – **злыдни, как известно**, – любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся.*

Оформление по правилам **вставки**.

(2) *Эти **экзаменаторы-злыдни**, как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся.*

Здесь **дефисное** написание слова.

**Указанное правило** сюда не подойдет (нет знака на месте вставки, а должна быть запятая): *Эти экзаменаторы  любят-таки придираться часто...*

Answer (score 1):

Есть много вариантов:

*Эти экзаменаторы – злыдни, как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся* — сочетание *как известно* к приложению не относится, а само приложение выделяется запятой и тире (второе тире опускается из-за требующейся запятой);

*Эти экзаменаторы – злыдни, — как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся* — вставная конструкция;

*Эти экзаменаторы, злыдни, как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся* — приложение можно обособить и запятыми, если пауза меньше;

*Эти экзаменаторы, злыдни как известно, любят-таки придираться часто, и никто не знает, к чему они в этот раз придерутся* — вводное сочетание *как известно* входит в уточняющий оборот и не отделяется от него запятой.

Все варианты верны, в том числе и в ответе выше — за что я ставлю плюс этому ответу, — но с разным смыслом и паузами.